# how to make custom dial pad xml design in android..?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I want to design custom dial pad with alphabets inn my application. is it better to with Table View or Grid View..?[image]

Comment: You can use this link https://github.com/guerrerocarlos/Custom-Sipdroid/tree/master/assets

Comment: Here you can find a library with different interface for a dial pad : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/PadLayout

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://bitbucket.org/dnaq/dialer2/src/f170814ddcda/res/layout/dialpad.xml?fileviewer=file-view-default) how to make custom dial pad:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/overlay_footer_background"
        android_layout_marginBottom="0"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textColor="@color/text_main"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical|center"
        android:textSize="24.0sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:editable="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Row1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/EditTextPhoneNumber">
      <!--  Buttons 1 2 3 -->
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button1"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_1_no_vm" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button2"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_2" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button3"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Buttons 4 5 6 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Row2"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Row1">

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button4"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_4" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button5"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_5" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button6"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_6" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Buttons 7 8 9 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Row3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Row2">
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button7"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_7" />
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button8"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_8" />
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button9"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_9" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Buttons * 0 # -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Row4"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Row3">
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/ButtonStar"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_star" />
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/Button0"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_0" />
      <ImageButton
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/ButtonHash"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          style="@style/DialerButton"
          android:src="@drawable/dial_num_pound" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Row5"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="48.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Row4">
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/ButtonContract"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
          android:src="@drawable/button_contract"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/ButtonCall"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:src="@drawable/button_call"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/ButtonDelete"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
          android:src="@drawable/button_backspace"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/calls_act_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".CallsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="@font/urbanist"
            android:text="08906587667777"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onePressed"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/two"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="twoPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/three"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="threePressed"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/four"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="fourPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/five"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="fivePressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/six"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="sixPressed"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/seven"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="sevenPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/eight"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="eightPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/nine"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="ninePressed"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="starPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/zero"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:onClick="zeroPressed"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hash"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="hashPressed"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```